# Generating a page on wordpress based on variable from the previous page

Tags: javascript, php, json, wordpress, endpoint

I've been googling and trying different things for weeks and at this point I'll just ask directly.

First note is this is all on Wordpress which seems to make everything more difficult.

What I want to do is click a link to direct me to a separate page. However, that link will have a specific ID depending which you click on. Therefore, all the links will technically bring you to the same page but as the page loads it will use the ID from the link to generate the data on the page.

All of my data is JSON based on various endpoints and I'm generating the pages data in a js file and inserting it into a div.

The data on the original page is generated in a for loop like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var trow = '<tr>';
    trow += '<td><a href="?id=' + data[i].itemID + '">' + data[i].info1 + '</a></td>';
    trow += '<td>' + data[i].info2 + '</td>';
    trow += '<td>' + data[i].info3 + '</td>';
    trow += '</tr>';
    table += trow;
}
```

So on the new page I'd generate it without a for loop using only data[*Whatever the ID was*].

Of two seeming solutions I have problems with both:

-I don't know how to send a variable through pages with javascript besides the href url thing but then don't know how to use that variable with javascript

-If I'm able to send it with PHP (which I also can't), I can't make the PHP variable into a javascript variable.

If anything is unclear let me know and I'll update you as soon as possible. Thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this in another question. It was able to accomplish what I need. Sorry if I didn't make it clear that this would work. Not having too much knowledge in wordpress I wasn't able to test the answers others gave very well but they may very well work, and work better.

```
var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
sParameterName,
i;

for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
    sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

    if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
        return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
    }
  }
}

var playerId = getUrlParameter('pid');
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'd need to add a rewrite so you can pick up request- which you do by adding the following into your theme's **functions.php** file:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_rewrites' );
function my_rewrites(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
            '^your-slug/([^/]*)/?',
            'index.php?your-slug-data-id=$matches[1]',
            'top'
    );
}
```

Then, create a new template file that will utilize this data. You need to add a hook so that when your rewrite runs it pulls in the right template file, like so:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'show_your_new_page', 1 );
function show_your_new_page( $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $wp_query->is_main_query() && isset( $wp_query->query['your-slug-data-id'] ) ) {
        include( TEMPLATEPATH . '-child/your-new-template.php' );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Now, in your new template file (your-new-template.php) you can get your passed ID by using `get_query_var( 'your-slug-data-id' )`

Once you've got your new page setup, you can simply change your table href to go to:
`<a href="/your-slug/' + data[i].itemID + '/">`

Comment: I'm going to try this method first but I have a few questions about what is placeholder and what is code. In the first block of code is "index.php" actually referencing that or just a placeholder in your example? Similarly, in the second block, is "TEMPLATEPATH" to be left like that or should I put the full path to the templates' location?

Comment: Both index.php and TEMPLATEPATH should be left as is. The items you should (optionally) change are: ```show_your_new_page```, ```your-new-template.php```, ```my_rewrites```, ```your-slug```, and ```your-slug-data-id```

Comment: Also note that once you add this rewrite you will need to refresh the wordpress rewrites in order for it to register this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can send and retrieve with PHP

```
http://myurlplace.com?id=123

Then retrieve it within say the header like:

$myVarId = $_GET['id'];

Then in your javascript

var myId = '<?=$myVarId?>';
```

I will stress this is a simple fix, it totally depends on your needs but this will work.

Comment: I know this is just an example, but I'd seriously avoid short tags. :\

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where the data is coming from, you can do several things.

Is this data coming from the database or from another an external source?

Comment: the data is coming from a database but as far as my understanding of an api endpoint goes I'm not calling directly from the database

Comment: Are you requesting the data from the browser (javascript) or from the server (php)?